# PHP validating individual form fields then all of them

Tags: php, forms

My simple php form validation script:

```
$email      = (isset($_POST['email'])) ? $_POST['email'] : '' ;
$password       = (isset($_POST['password'])) ? $_POST['password'] : '' ;
$fname      = (isset($_POST['fname'])) ? $_POST['fname'] : '' ;
$lname      = (isset($_POST['lname'])) ? $_POST['lname'] : '' ;

if (!empty($email) && !empty($password) && !empty($fname) && !empty($lname)) {
    $auth->createAccount($email, $password, $fname, $lname);
}
```

For some reason it doesn't look very good to me.

How can I check each form field to indicate which one is the one that needs filling out and then at the end check to make sure all fields are filled out before calling the `createAccount()` function.

Note: the `createAccount()` function sanitizes the input so there is no need to do this here.

Comment: you can use jquery for this..

Comment: I don't know why you're using a ternary then checking if they're empty. It defeats the purpose really.

Comment: Yes I can use jQuery but what if JavaScript is turned off?

Comment: how about using `<noscript>`? if js is disabled/doesn't support js put something in there to notify user that js is turned off?

Comment: why not put `required` in input and validate with jQuery, make users life easy when they filling the form

Comment: @Shehary not all browsers supports HTML5..

Comment: @Shehary Because a malicious user could still send a POST request with whatever he wants in it. Just let the guy validate user input on the server side! Sheesh.

Comment: @kittykittybangbang, not suggesting to not validate the form on server side, just making things easier for users who fill forms and after submission they figure out that they forget something `each form field to indicate which one is the one that needs filling out` and with server validation, OP has to make sure if there is an error on page refresh all the already filled values be there which in this case I don't see any such approach and atleast with jQuery validation OP has only to validate `then at the end check to make sure all fields are filled out before calling the createAccount()`

Comment: @Shehary - you can check on the client side; but you need to check server-side, too. Malicious users can submit things by bypassing your validation, and if you're not validating on the server, too, then they can add whatever they want to your database.

Comment: @andrewsi thanks for telling me what others already told me but what I don't understand where I told OP not to validated the form on server side please please please point me where i said not validate the from on server side?

Comment: @Shehary - you are quite correct, and I apologise for having mis-read what you typed.

Comment: @andrewsi, Thank you so much, finally someone (you) understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$form_names = array(
    'email' => 'e-mail', 
    'password' => 'password',
    'fname' => 'firstname',
    'lname' => 'lastname'
); //So that the user understands the errors better
$errors = array();
foreach ($_POST as $field=>$val) {
    if (empty($val)) {
        array_push($errors, 'Please fill out ' . $form_names[$field]);
    }
}
if (count($errors) == 0) {
    //No errors call the submit PHP function
}
else {
    $string = implode('<br/>', $errors);
    echo '<p style="color:red;">' . $string . '</p>';
}
?>
```

However, the setback is that form names should be appropriate to echo out to the user in an intelligible way. As some may require spaces, you can create an array for form names connected to their actual and use that value to echo out to the user via. `$good_name = $form_names[$field]`

Comment: No need to put in all the POST arrays for this ;-) that's what I also had in mind after seeing what the OP seems to want to achieve.

Comment: I like your simple solution. If you could include the array of form fields that you described as the setback it would make your answer even better.

Comment: I included an edit, the new array just makes the errors make more sense (for example fname vs. firstname). Also @Fred-ii- , sorry if I'm misunderstanding you, but what exactly do you mean by "all the POST arrays"?

Comment: @Valkyrie Meaning, that one doesn't have to to do `$_POST['var1']` - `$_POST['var2']` - `$_POST['var3']` etc. the foreach takes care of that, as you wrote it.

Comment: Oh! Sorry I mis-read your comment. I thought you meant I was checking over redundant array values in $_POST. Sorry about that, and thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Most common way to deal with this that I've seen is to create an array:

```
if (!$_POST['email']) {$errors[] = 'Email field is empty.';}
if (!$_POST['password']) {$errors[] = 'Password field is empty.';}
if (!$_POST['fname']) {$errors[] = 'First name field is empty.';}
if (!$_POST['lname']) {$errors[] = 'Last name field is empty.';}
```

And then loop through the errors to display them:

```
foreach ($errors as $error) {
    echo $error.'<br>';
}
```